# Insert text at highest tree level in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I am trying to insert some HTML and some text in a `contenteditable`.
However, when I'm in this configuration:

```
Some text <span>A span tag</span>
```

If I have my caret at the end of the text and try to insert some text like this:

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, ' my text');
```

Instead of getting what I expect:

```
Some text <span>A span tag</span> my text
```

I get this:

```
Some text <span>A span tag my text</span>
```

How can I force `insertHTML` to insert at the highest level?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to set the carretPosition at the end of the selection and then insert your html, I made a small snippet demonstrating this behavior

One you set the range based on a node, you can then choose to [`selection.collapseToEnd()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/collapseToEnd) like so:

```
currentSelection.collapseToEnd();
```

The snippet uses the mousedown event to make sure the focus stays on the contenteditable item

```js
document.querySelector('#addContentButton').addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  var currentSelection = window.getSelection();
  // make sure there is a range available
  if (currentSelection.rangeCount > 0) {
    // get the container from where it started
    var target = currentSelection.getRangeAt(0).startContainer;
    var range = document.createRange();
    // check if it has any childNodes, if so take the last node otherwise choose the container itself
    var targetNode = target.childNodes && target.childNodes.length ? target.childNodes[target.childNodes.length - 1] : target;

    // select the node
    range.selectNode( targetNode );
    // remove all ranges from the window
    currentSelection.removeAllRanges();
    // add the new range
    currentSelection.addRange( range );
    // set the position of the carret at the end
    currentSelection.collapseToEnd();
    // focus the element if posible
    target.focus && target.focus();

    // insert the html at the end
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, 'test');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});

document.querySelector('#insertCurrentPosition').addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  var currentSelection = window.getSelection();
  // make sure there is a range available
  if (currentSelection.rangeCount > 0) {
    // get the container from where it started
    var target = currentSelection.getRangeAt(0).startContainer;
    // focus the element if posible
    target.focus && target.focus();
    // insert the html at the end
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, 'test');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
span {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">This is <span>my span</span><span>and another one</span></div>

<button id="addContentButton">Append at end of editable element</button>
<button id="insertCurrentPosition">Insert at current position</button>
```

Comment: What if I have this : `This is <span>some HTML</span><span>with multiple spans</span>` and I want to insert some text between the two spans?

Comment: @Mat that's a totally different question, you asked clearly to insert something at the end of the selection, however you just don't change the selection, you just skip selection of the new range and the setting of the range. Could it be your main problem was with keeping the focus?

Comment: @Mat I added a second button that adds the text at the current range, allowing you do to what you want

Answer (score -2):

Not sure I 100% understand your question / problem, but inserting text into a span element is as simple as this:

HTML:

```
<span id="mySpan"></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML = "Text to put inside span";
```

'contenteditable' simple returns a true/false indicating whether an object can or cannot be edited.

Hope this helped

Comment: No, you didn't understand my question. I have a `contenteditable`div in which I have the HTML I described. I am trying to use the `execCommand` to insert some text after the caret position.